# PHP create new file without warning: "No such file"

Tags: php, file, warnings

I want to create a new .txt file via php like this:

```
    $file = 'students.txt';
    // opens file to load the current content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // add new content to file
    $current .= $_POST["name"] . " : " . $_POST["grade"] . PHP_EOL;
    // writes content to file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

It works fine but I get a warning when the file does not exist at the beginning. That's not a problem because php creates the file in this case, but how can I prevent this warning message from appearing on the screen?

Comment: Well, obviously you can simply _test_ if the file exist. Or you can `touch` it.

Comment: `$current = ''; if(file_exists($file)) { $current = file_get_contents($file);  }`

Comment: I don't recommend suppressing errors/warning  You could just as easily check if the file exists prior to opening it with `is_file`  but  ` $current = @file_get_contents($file);` should suppress the warning

Comment: Oh of course... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use fopen in `a`(append) mode read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
// opens file to load the current content
if ($file = fopen('students.txt', 'a')){
   // add new content to file and writes content to file
   fwrite($file ,$_POST["name"] . " : " . $_POST["grade"] . PHP_EOL);
   // close file
   fclose($file);
   exit(0);
}
else {
   echo "Cannot open file";
   exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FILE_APPEND` option to `file_put_contents()` to append to the file, so you don't have to read it first. It will create the file if necessary.

```
$file = 'students.txt';
$current = $_POST["name"] . " : " . $_POST["grade"] . PHP_EOL;
// writes content to file
file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);
```